# soap var in php with objects and repeated tags

Tags: php, object, soap

I am working on a very extensive soap client and want to use objects for all of my data. I need to produce something like this:

```
<Animals>
    <Cat>
        <Name>Bob</Name>
    </Cat>
    <Cat>
        <Name>Peter</Name>
    </Cat>
    <Dog>
        <Name>Rex</Name>
    </Dog>
</Animals>
```

So my Animals Object would look something like this with the same code for dogs as well: (Each of the "Cats" would be an object with a simple property Name)

```
<?php

use ArrayObject;

class Animals {

public function __construct(){
    $this->Cat = new ArrayObject();
}

/**
 * Cat
 * @var \ArrayObject
 */
protected $Cat;

/**
 * Adds a Cat
 * @param \SoapVar $cat
 */
public function addCat(\SoapVar $cat) {
    $this->Cat->append($cat);
    return $this;
}
```

The problem is that this does not produce the result I want. The result would look like something like this.

```
<Animals>
    <Cat>
        <Cat>
            <Name>Bob</Name>
        </Cat>
        <Cat>
            <Name>Peter</Name>
        </Cat>
    </Cat>
    <Dog>
        <Dog>
            <Name>Rex</Name>
        </Dog>
    </Dog>
</Animals>
```

It seems like SoapVar and SOAP_ENC_OBJECT creates a tag for every property in the object. This creates these extra tags that I do not want. Is there any way to create repeating tags inside the main object? Changing Animals to an ArrayObject is not acceptable for my object oriented architecture.

Edit:
I found a new possible solution. If I add an iterator to my class that goes through my properties correctly and encode the object using SOAP_ENC_ARRAY. It creates the proper xml structure I want. The problem right now is just that every tag is called `<xsd:anyType>`

Comment: Seems to me like it's doing exactly what you're asking it to do.  Either append the individual `$cat`s directly to `Animal` or, have the outer item be `Cats` instead of `Cat` so that it makes more sense.

Comment: @PatrickQ how can I append the individual `$cat`s directly to the `Animal` object? That would completely solve my problem

Comment: Can you provide some more code to make this reproducible? Also, you're appending a `$cat` object to your `$this->Cat` property. Just a guess, but have you tried appending it to `$this`? Ie. `$this->append($cat);`

Comment: @waterloomatt I would love to do something like `$this->append($cat);` . The problem is that a regular object just does not have an `append` method like the an ArrayObject has and I don't know of any option of adding data to an object without using properties.

I will try to provide some more code later, but I think that the soap call will be hard to reproduce without the actual WSDL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem:

I knew how to solve the problem using ArrayObjects but did not want to give up using my own classes. Now, I am including a method in my class that returns the object as an ArrayObject for further use.

```
function encode(){
    $arrayObject = new ArrayObject();
    foreach($this->Cat as $cat){
        $arrayObject->append($cat);
    }
    foreach($this->Dog as $dog){
        $arrayObject->append($dog);
    }
    return $arrayObject;
}
```

and I can then turn this ArrayObject into the XML Structure I need.

(Credit also goes to Marcel and his blog post at http://www.mm-newmedia.de/2017/10/php-und-bipro-sich-wiederholende-elemente-im-soap-request/ )

Comment: Thank you for metioning my blog. ;)